# Continuity of infimum of a function whose domain of interest varies with its input

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Consider a continuous function $f:D \rightarrow \R$ where $D \subseteq \R^n$. Let $\{x\in \R^n | \Vert x \Vert \leq r \} \subseteq D$ for some $r > 0$ where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is any $p$-norm. Now consider $\psi:[0,r] \rightarrow \R$ defined by

$$
\psi(s) = \inf_{s \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq r}{f(x)}
$$
Then, can we show that $\psi$ is continuous using tools of analysis, i.e., $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument? I am unfamiliar with the structure of the function. I tried to use the definition of infimum: For all $s \in [0,r]$,

$$
\forall x \in D: s \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq r \Rightarrow f(x) \geq \psi(s)
$$
and
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists x \in D: s \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq r \land f(x) < \psi (s) + \epsilon
$$
But I could not find a clue for this.

Comment: It will help to notice that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\{x:\Vert x\Vert\le r\}$.